# App is closing without crash

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I creating exam app in android and loading questions in viewpager. When i moving one to another question app is getting closed without crash and.

```
FragmentPagerAdapter mFragmentPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), takeExamResponse.getPayloads().getQuestions(), mFragmentNavigator, takeExamResponse.getPayloads().getType(), "finished".equals(getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("IS_FINISHED")) ? true : false, mQuestionsFragment);
viewPager.setAdapter(mFragmentPagerAdapter);
```

Adapter class.

```
package com.comquest.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import com.comquest.fragment.ViewPagerFragment;
import com.comquest.interfaces.FragmentNavigator;
import com.comquest.response.Question;
import com.comquest.utilities.ExamGuruApplication;

import java.util.List;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Question> takeExamResponse;
    private final Context context;
    FragmentNavigator fragmentNavigator;
    String type = "";
    private boolean isFinshed;
    private ExamGuruApplication.Listener mListener;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm, List<Question> response, FragmentNavigator fragmentNavigator, String type, boolean isFinshed, ExamGuruApplication.Listener mListener) {
        super(fm);
        this.takeExamResponse = response;
        this.isFinshed = isFinshed;
        this.context = context;
        this.mListener = mListener;
        this.fragmentNavigator = fragmentNavigator;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ViewPagerFragment.newInstance(context, takeExamResponse.get(position), fragmentNavigator, type, isFinshed, mListener, position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return takeExamResponse.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
     06-11 10:46:49.113 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallObjectMethod called with pending exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for WebView
06-11 10:46:49.113 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int) (MessageQueue.java:-2)
06-11 10:46:49.113 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.os.Message android.os.MessageQueue.next() (MessageQueue.java:323)
06-11 10:46:49.113 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:135)
06-11 10:46:49.113 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:5443)
06-11 10:46:49.113 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
06-11 10:46:49.113 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:728)
06-11 10:46:49.113 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-11 10:46:49.113 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] 
06-11 10:46:49.113 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     in call to CallObjectMethod
06-11 10:46:49.113 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     from void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int)
06-11 10:46:49.113 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
06-11 10:46:49.113 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x74b9f2a0 self=0xb8e92d20
06-11 10:46:49.113 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | sysTid=19776 nice=-4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f2fb34
06-11 10:46:49.113 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | state=R schedstat=( 23113299218 2900635621 29799 ) utm=2082 stm=229 core=0 HZ=100
06-11 10:46:49.113 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | stack=0xbe0ef000-0xbe0f1000 stackSize=8MB
06-11 10:46:49.113 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
06-11 10:46:49.113 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #00 pc 0035ca0d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+116)
06-11 10:46:49.113 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #01 pc 0033d863  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+138)
06-11 10:46:49.113 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #02 pc 0024f719  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+760)
06-11 10:46:49.113 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #03 pc 0024fdb7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortV(char const*, char const*, std::__va_list)+54)
06-11 10:46:49.113 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #04 pc 000fc0b3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::AbortF(char const*, ...)+30)
06-11 10:46:49.114 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #05 pc 00100f8f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::Check(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, bool, char const*, art::JniValueType*) (.constprop.95)+5054)
06-11 10:46:49.114 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #06 pc 0010f043  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallMethodV(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list, art::Primitive::Type, art::InvokeType)+498)
06-11 10:46:49.114 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #07 pc 0011061f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallObjectMethod(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+38)
06-11 10:46:49.114 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #08 pc 00002bc3  /system/lib/libnativehelper.so (jniGetReferent+94)
06-11 10:46:49.114 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #09 pc 000750bb  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeDisplayEventReceiver::dispatchVsync(long long, int, unsigned int)+26)
06-11 10:46:49.114 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #10 pc 000752dd  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeDisplayEventReceiver::handleEvent(int, int, void*)+80)
06-11 10:46:49.114 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #11 pc 00012ebf  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+530)
06-11 10:46:49.114 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #12 pc 00012f8f  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+130)
06-11 10:46:49.114 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #13 pc 00081169  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, int)+22)
06-11 10:46:49.114 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #14 pc 00000585  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+96)
06-11 10:46:49.114 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
06-11 10:46:49.114 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
06-11 10:46:49.114 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-11 10:46:49.114 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
06-11 10:46:49.114 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
06-11 10:46:49.114 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
06-11 10:46:49.114 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-11 10:46:49.114 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] 
06-11 10:46:50.937 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399] Runtime aborting...
06-11 10:46:50.937 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399] Aborting thread:
06-11 10:46:50.937 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399] "main" prio=7 tid=1 Native
06-11 10:46:50.937 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x74b9f2a0 self=0xb8e92d20
06-11 10:46:50.937 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | sysTid=19776 nice=-4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f2fb34
06-11 10:46:50.937 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | state=R schedstat=( 23166860878 2904946150 29911 ) utm=2083 stm=233 core=0 HZ=100
06-11 10:46:50.937 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | stack=0xbe0ef000-0xbe0f1000 stackSize=8MB
06-11 10:46:50.937 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | held mutexes= "abort lock"
06-11 10:46:50.937 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #00 pc 0035ca0d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+116)
06-11 10:46:50.937 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #01 pc 0033d863  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+138)
06-11 10:46:50.937 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #02 pc 00321955  /system/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::DumpThread(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, art::Thread*) const+20)
06-11 10:46:50.937 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #03 pc 00321bc9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+532)
06-11 10:46:50.937 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #04 pc 000f3d0d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+2212)
06-11 10:46:50.937 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #05 pc 0024fa15  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1524)
06-11 10:46:50.937 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #06 pc 0024fdb7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortV(char const*, char const*, std::__va_list)+54)
06-11 10:46:50.937 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #07 pc 000fc0b3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::AbortF(char const*, ...)+30)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #08 pc 00100f8f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::Check(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, bool, char const*, art::JniValueType*) (.constprop.95)+5054)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #09 pc 0010f043  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallMethodV(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list, art::Primitive::Type, art::InvokeType)+498)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #10 pc 0011061f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallObjectMethod(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+38)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #11 pc 00002bc3  /system/lib/libnativehelper.so (jniGetReferent+94)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #12 pc 000750bb  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeDisplayEventReceiver::dispatchVsync(long long, int, unsigned int)+26)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #13 pc 000752dd  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeDisplayEventReceiver::handleEvent(int, int, void*)+80)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #14 pc 00012ebf  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+530)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #15 pc 00012f8f  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+130)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #16 pc 00081169  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, int)+22)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #17 pc 00000585  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (???)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399] Pending exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for WebView
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int) (MessageQueue.java:-2)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at android.os.Message android.os.MessageQueue.next() (MessageQueue.java:323)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:135)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:5443)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:728)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock mutator lock
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399] All threads:
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399] DALVIK THREADS (45):
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399] "main" prio=7 tid=1 Runnable
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x74b9f2a0 self=0xb8e92d20
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | sysTid=19776 nice=-4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f2fb34
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | state=R schedstat=( 23208650202 2906838650 29936 ) utm=2084 stm=236 core=0 HZ=100
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | stack=0xbe0ef000-0xbe0f1000 stackSize=8MB
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #00 pc 0035ca0d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+116)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #01 pc 0033d863  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+138)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #02 pc 003471d3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*)+422)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #03 pc 00347d1b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::RunCheckpoint(art::Closure*)+194)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #04 pc 00348241  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)+124)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #05 pc 00321b4b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+406)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #06 pc 000f3d0d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+2212)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #07 pc 0024fa15  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1524)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #08 pc 0024fdb7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortV(char const*, char const*, std::__va_list)+54)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #09 pc 000fc0b3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::AbortF(char const*, ...)+30)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #10 pc 00100f8f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::Check(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, bool, char const*, art::JniValueType*) (.constprop.95)+5054)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #11 pc 0010f043  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallMethodV(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list, art::Primitive::Type, art::InvokeType)+498)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #12 pc 0011061f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallObjectMethod(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+38)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #13 pc 00002bc3  /system/lib/libnativehelper.so (jniGetReferent+94)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #14 pc 000750bb  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeDisplayEventReceiver::dispatchVsync(long long, int, unsigned int)+26)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #15 pc 000752dd  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeDisplayEventReceiver::handleEvent(int, int, void*)+80)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #16 pc 00012ebf  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+530)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #17 pc 00012f8f  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+130)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #18 pc 00081169  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, int)+22)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #19 pc 00000585  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+96)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399] 
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399] "Signal Catcher" prio=7 tid=2 WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c070a0 self=0xb90e7f70
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | sysTid=19781 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb44e5930
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | state=S schedstat=( 1075832 378907 2 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | stack=0xb43e9000-0xb43eb000 stackSize=1014KB
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | held mutexes=
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #00 pc 000431e0  /system/lib/libc.so (__rt_sigtimedwait+12)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #01 pc 0001c177  /system/lib/libc.so (sigwait+22)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #02 pc 003285c1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::WaitForSignal(art::Thread*, art::SignalSet&)+60)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #03 pc 003296ff  /system/lib/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::Run(void*)+210)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #04 pc 00041acb  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+30)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #05 pc 00019355  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   (no managed stack frames)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399] 
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399] "JDWP" prio=7 tid=3 WaitingInMainDebuggerLoop
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c07100 self=0xb90e58e0
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | sysTid=19782 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb43e1930
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | state=S schedstat=( 3815666793 264560002 3177 ) utm=361 stm=20 core=1 HZ=100
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | stack=0xb42e5000-0xb42e7000 stackSize=1014KB
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | held mutexes=
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #00 pc 000430fc  /system/lib/libc.so (__pselect6+20)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #01 pc 0001b4c5  /system/lib/libc.so (select+60)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #02 pc 003ea79f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JDWP::JdwpAdbState::ProcessIncoming()+202)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #03 pc 0025b293  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JDWP::JdwpState::Run()+298)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #04 pc 0025c0ff  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JDWP::StartJdwpThread(void*)+10)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #05 pc 00041acb  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+30)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   native: #06 pc 00019355  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
06-11 10:46:50.938 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   (no managed stack frames)
06-11 10:46:50.940 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399] 
06-11 10:46:50.940 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399] "ReferenceQueueDaemon" prio=7 tid=4 Waiting
06-11 10:46:50.940 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c07160 self=0xb8fba938
06-11 10:46:50.940 19776-19776/exam.comquest.test A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:399]   | sysTid=19783 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb42db930
```

Comment: Remote exception,channel broken unrecoverably.

Comment: Post the activity code.

Comment: Which fragment child or parent

Comment: Parent. The exception is not making sense.

Comment: @Uday posted the exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114400/discussion-between-uday-and-boopathi).

Comment: can you send your webview